# Is the actor for Albus Severus Potter one of the triplets who played Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, actor-identification

This has been going around a bit on Facebook with some people I know:

[image: Albus Potter is Baby Potter]

The site in the image, [LOLSPIC.com](http://lolspic.com/), seems to contain just user-submitted funny/interesting images, and doesn't seem to be a troll site...

Albus Severus Potter's actor was [Arthur Bowen](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Bowen), and baby Harry Potter is credited as [the Saunders triplets](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Saunders_triplets).  Neither appear to have anything in common over at IMDB, either ([Bowen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4096849/), [Saunders](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1196732/)), but Saunders may not be their real name..?  And sadly, Bowen doesn't have a Wikipedia page - if you try to look him up, it redirects to [List of Harry Potter cast members#Epilogue characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Harry_Potter_cast_members#Epilogue_characters).

Sooo, anyone have more information?  *Is* Arthur Bowen one of the Saunders triplets, or is someone just pulling one over on us?

Comment: More importantlu, WTH is a baby of a brunette and a redhead getting his hair color from a recessive gene? :)

Comment: @DVK Arthur Bowen looks brunette to me..  His hair is the same shade mine gets when I'm outside a lot in the summer (at least in that screenshot).

Comment: @DVK It is entirely possible for Albus to have red hair, after all Harry's parents had brown hair (James) and red hair (Lily), so Harry could have been a carrier for the recessive red-hair gene which, when mixed with Ginny's double trait for red hair, provides a 50% chance for Harry and Ginny's kids to have red hair as well.... But I'm pretty sure Albus has brown hair, and the lighting in this scene/image just makes it look more red than it actually is.....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That pic is not from *HP* 1 -- it's from *HP* 8, from the Snape's memories scene. The baby shown in the original meme is named Toby Papworth. The babies named in *HP 1* are the Saunders triplets. So the answer has to be no, Toby Papworth, the Saunders triplets, and Arthur Bowen (Albus Severus Potter) are not all the same person/actor.

[image: Baby Harry in *Philosopher's Stone*]

[image: Baby Harry in *Philosopher's Stone* 2]

Above is baby Harry, one of the Saunders triplets, in *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, which was released in [2001](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0241527/). As a little bit of trivia, baby Harry in *Sorcerer's Stone* is wearing a striped *Blue's Clues* romper/pajama set while sitting in his crib as Voldemort approaches. *Blue's Clues* didn't exist in 1981.

[image: Albus Severus Potter in *Deathly Hallows 2*]

Above is Arthur Bowen, the actor credited with playing Albus Severus Potter in *Deathly Hallows 2*. Not only is his name completely different than the actors who played baby Harry in *Sorcerer's Stone*, but his eyes appear to be a lighter blue than the Saunders triplet pictured, and he seems to have a cleft in his chin when the Saunders triplet does not.

[image: Baby Harry in *Deathly Hallows 2*]

And above here is baby Harry in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2*, which was released in [2011](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/). This is Toby Papworth. You'll notice baby Harry in *Deathly Hallows 2* is not wearing a striped romper like he is in *Sorcerer's Stone*; In *Deathly Hallows 2* his romper is plain light blue. As well, the cut on Harry's forehead is more pronounced in the *Deathly Hallows 2* scene than in the one from *Sorcerer's Stone*. Toby Papworth also does not appear to have a cleft in his chin as Arthur Bowen does.

Comment: Or they could have attributed the wrong baby to the image.

Comment: _Very_ good point about the image used (I do feel kinda silly about that), but like @NominSim says, the claim is about (one of?) the triplets from the first movie

Comment: @Izkata - No reason to feel silly, IMO. Well, the original meme in the original question has baby Harry from *HP* 8, not 1. So it's impossible that that same child played Albus Severus as well. If it were the baby Harry from movie 1, it might have actually been possible, but IMDB doesn't reflect that. :)